# removeSource() returning error on internal package function

Tags: r

In my package, I have the following internal function, `.batStats()`

```
> .batStats
function(x)
{
    wData <- weightsData[rownames(weightsData) %in% x$yearID, ]
    wOBA <- .wOBA(x, wData)
    wRC <- .wRC(x, wData, wOBA)
    stats <- with(x, {
        cbind(
            PA = { AB + BB + HBP + SH + SF },
            TB = assign("TB", { (H - X2B - X3B - HR) + 2 * X2B + 3 * X3B + 4 * HR } ),
            AVG = { H/AB },
            OBP = { (H + BB + HBP)/(AB + SF + BB + HBP) },
            SLG = { TB/AB },
            ISO = { (X2B + 2 * X3B + 3 * HR)/AB },
            wOBA = wOBA,
            wRC = wRC)
    })
    rownames(stats) <- x$yearID
    round(stats, 3)
}
```

When I call `removeSource()` on it, I get the following error

```
> removeSource(.batStats)
# Error in recurse(part[[i]]) : argument "part" is missing, with no default
```

I don't get this error with any other function in the package, including internals beginning with `.`.   Furthermore, when I pull the `recurse()` function out of the `removeSource()` source code and do

```
> recurse(.batStats)
```

there is no error. But there is an error with

```
> recurse(body(.batStats))
# Error in attr(part, "srcref") <- NULL : 
#   argument "*tmp*" is missing, with no default
```

How I can get `removeSource()` to work on this `.batStats()` function?

Comment: What is the point of the call to `assign` in `PA = assign("PA", { AB + BB + HBP + SH + SF } )` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to be caused by the

```
wData <- weightsData[rownames(weightsData) %in% x$yearID, ]
```

line. `removeSource()` is trying to remove the source from every element, and when it reached the blank index in the `[,]` subset set, it seems to trigger an error because it can't remove the source from the empty index.

You can change that line to

```
wData <- weightsData[rownames(weightsData) %in% x$yearID, seq_along(weightsData)]
```

to avoid the error. Seems like it could be a bug in the `removeSource()` function. A minimal, reproducible example is

```
test <- function(a) {
    a[1,]
}
removeSource(test)
```