# removeSource() with `[` subset fails on empty j argument

Tags: r

This is a follow-up to [removeSource() returning error on internal package function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336662/removesource-returning-error-on-internal-package-function).

In that question, it was pointed out that there may be a bug in `removeSource()` when the function uses `[` subsetting.  I want to focus on that issue, so I wrote a new question here.

When the  `j` argument in `[` is empty, `removeSource()` fails.

Here's an example.

```
foo <- function(x) { x[1, ] }
removeSource(foo)
# Error in recurse(part[[i]]) : argument "part" is missing, with no default
bar <- function(x) { x[1, seq_along(x)] }
removeSource(bar)
# function (x) 
# {
#     x[1, seq_along(x)]
# }
```

I'm hesitant to call it a bug, so I'll first ask if this was done intentionally?  Also, suppose I submitted the `foo()` function in a package to CRAN.  Would it pass the testing?

**Updates:**

1. Sept 1, 2014: Bug report filed https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15957
2. Sept 21, 2014: This was indeed a bug and according to the confirmed bug report is *"soon to be fixed in R-devel and R-patched."*
3. **Fixed** in version R 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it was a bug. No sign of it reported here though:

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=removeSource

Interestingly you get a different error once you try and debug the function by making a local copy.

```
> dput(removeSource,file="rs.tmp.R")
> rs = dget("rs.tmp.R")
```

`rs` is now a copy of `removeSource`, but not in the environment of the utils package.

```
> foo = function(x){x[1,]}
> rs(foo)
Error in `attr<-`(`*tmp*`, "srcref", value = NULL) : '*tmp*' is missing
> removeSource(foo)
Error in recurse(part[[i]]) : argument "part" is missing, with no default
```

`rs` works fine on a function without missing subs:

```
> bar = function(x){x[1]}
> rs(bar)
function (x) 
{
    x[1]
}
```

If you want a really minimal failing example, you don't need any subscripts or commas:

```
> foo = function(x){x[]}
> removeSource(foo)
Error in recurse(part[[i]]) : argument "part" is missing, with no default
```

I doubt this will trigger any CRAN flags since missing dimensions in subscripts probably occur in 90% of the packages currently on there...

Suggest you report it on the bug tracker, or ask on R-devel mailing list.